# how to either get rid of the commas added (by default) between tags in Refinery CMS?

Tags: html, erb, refinerycms

My goal is to customize the tags for blog posts in the Refinery CMS. By default they are not styled. I added some styling just to test that I was making changes to the right areas (yes I know it is ugly).

[image: currently needs work]

But my goal intent is to get them in a format similar to what I have on my own blog.

[image: goal of tags]

Refinery is adding a comma after each tag. What should I modify in the html or css to not add the commas?

**app/views/refinery/blog/shared/_tags.html.erb**

```
<% if @tags.any? %>
  <h2>Tag Cloud</h2>
  <nav id='tags'>
    <% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
      <%= link_to tag.name, refinery.blog_tagged_posts_path(tag.id, tag.name.parameterize), :class => css_class %>
    <% end %>
  </nav>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag_cloud method is a method found in the acts-as-taggable-on library that the refinerycms-blog extension uses. More information can be found out about it in the [readme](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#tag-cloud-calculations) for the library.

Comment: Oh so I think I was used to Tumblr where you add a comma after each tag. So I actually did that between tags. So what is the basic high level explanation about how tagging works in refinery? I have some tags that are 2 or 3 words and needed to see how to properly make that happen.